# Handling multiline text fields while extracting data from Salesforce using pyspark

Tags: python, salesforce, pyspark

I am trying to extract Salesforce data using pyspark in following manner:

```
df = spark.read.format("com.springml.spark.salesforce").option("soql","some SOQLquery").option("login","https://test.salesforce.com").option("username","myuser").option("password","mypassword").option("version","45.0").option("multiLine","true").option("inferSchema","true").option("bulk","true").option("wholeFile","true").option("sfObject","some object").load()
```

There is a field in the Salesforce object which is having some multiline text data.
While reading the Salesforce data in df; I am getting the data merged among the columns because of the multiline text.
Is there any way I can handle the multiline text?

Comment: Spark usually support multiline read (in CSV and JSON case) though the multiline option, which you have in your code, however right before that option you have a wrong quoting: 
 `.option("version",45.0")`
The beginner quote is missing from the 45.0

Comment: missing double quote was a typo; but keeping multiline option as TRUE here is not solving my issue.